# Get datePublished from url in Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, html, date, url

I'm trying to access "datePublished" from [here](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/minecraft-java-edition-1-17-1). It is visible in source code as:

```
"datePublished": "2021-07-06T13:42:49.957+0000",
```

In order to get: "2021-07-06T13:42:49.957+0000"

Preview of page here:
[Preview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Geyhi.png)

Many thanks

Comment: You need to learn how to get data from the URL and parse the received JSON.

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit?
Thanks